# log4j2 Custom Filter Plugin is not working on websphere . Getting error : RollingFile contains an invalid element or attribute "UALevelMatchFilter

Tags: log4j

On Websphere 8.5x
I am getting following error
RollingFile contains an invalid element or attribute "UALevelMatchFilter"

**Configuration XML is as given below and it contains the package attribute which has the class **

<Configuration packages="**com.unica.afc.logger"** monitorInterval="60" status="trace">

```
    <!-- ======================================================== -->
    <!-- Console Log Appender                                     -->
    <!--                                                          -->
    <!-- ======================================================== -->
    <Console name="CONSOLE_LOG" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p %F.%M:%L: %m%n"/>
            <!-- only the levels (comma separated) specified in LevelToMatch will be logged -->.
            <UALevelMatchFilter levelToMatch="DEBUG, WARN,INFO, ERROR, FATAL" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
</Console>

    <!-- =================== -->
    <!-- System Log Appender -->
    <!-- =================== -->
    <RollingFile  name="SYS_LOG" fileName="${sys:plan.home}/logs/system.log"
            filePattern="${sys:plan.home}/logs/system.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}"
            immediateFlush="false" append="true" >

            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%X{user}] %-5p %F.%M:%L: %m%n" />
            <Policies>
                    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
            <UALevelMatchFilter levelToMatch="DEBUG, WARN,INFO, ERROR, FATAL" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
    </RollingFile>
```

.
.
.

The implementation of class is given below

```
@Plugin(name = "UALevelMatchFilter", category = "Core", elementType = "filter", printObject = true)
public class UALevelMatchFilter extends AbstractFilter
{
    private Vector<Level> levelToMatch;
     
    private UALevelMatchFilter(Vector<Level> levels, Result onMatch, Result onMismatch) {
        super(onMatch, onMismatch);
        this.levelToMatch = levels;
    }
 
    public Result filter(Logger logger, Level level, Marker marker, String msg, Object[] params) {
        return filter(level);
    }
 
    public Result filter(Logger logger, Level level, Marker marker, Object msg, Throwable t) {
        return filter(level);
    }
 
    public Result filter(Logger logger, Level level, Marker marker, Message msg, Throwable t) {
        return filter(level);
    }
 
    @Override
    public Result filter(LogEvent event) {
        return filter(event.getLevel());
    }
 
    private Result filter(Level level) {
        //return level.isMoreSpecificThan(this.level) ? onMatch : onMismatch;
        for(Level currentLevel:levelToMatch){
            if(currentLevel.equals(level)){
                return onMatch;
            }
        }
        return onMismatch;
    }
 
 
    /**
     * Create a ThresholdFilter.
     * @param loggerLevel The log Level.
     * @param match The action to take on a match.
     * @param mismatch The action to take on a mismatch.
     * @return The created ThresholdFilter.
     */
    @PluginFactory
    public static UALevelMatchFilter createFilter(@PluginAttribute (value = "LevelToMatch", defaultString = "DEBUG") String levelStr,
                                               @PluginAttribute(value = "onMatch", defaultString = "NEUTRAL") Result onMatch,
                                               @PluginAttribute(value = "onMismatch", defaultString = "DENY") Result onMismatch) {
        String [] levelStrArr = levelStr.split(",");
        Vector<Level> levels = new Vector<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < levelStrArr.length; i++) {
            levels.add(Level.toLevel(levelStrArr[i].trim()));
        }
        return new UALevelMatchFilter(levels, onMatch, onMismatch);
    }
    
    /**
     * parameter level format: "DEBUG, INFO, SQL, ..."
     */
    public void setLevelToMatch(String levels)
    {       
        //System.out.println("UAPLevelMatchFilter.setLevelToMatch: setting levels to >>> " + levels);
        if (levels != null && levels.trim().length() > 0)
        {
            if (levelToMatch == null) levelToMatch = new Vector();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(levels,",");
            String level = null;
            while (st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                level = st.nextToken();
                //System.out.println("^^^^^^^ level ==== " + level);
                levelToMatch.add(Level.toLevel(level.trim()));         //TODO what about custom levels   
            }
        }
    }
```

Also,  the class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.ResolveUtil has some debug statements but those are not getting printed even after adding status="trace"

Also, the console shows  DEBUG Took 0.001806 seconds to load 0 plugins from package com.unica.afc.logger

Could you let me know if I am missing something

The classes in mentioned in the package are present in the product's jar file which is under WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 0):

1. Using the packages element is not recommended and should only be used as a last resort. Instead, you should ensure that annotation processing is enabled so that Log4j can add your plugin to a Log4jPlugins.dat file. That mechanism is much faster than resorting to classpath scanning at runtime.
2. If you add verbose="true" to your Configuration element you should see the output of scanning for plugins. You don't see the output of ResolverUtil because the log level isn't set until after plugin scanning.